# how to make a listview that contain arrays?

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, bitmap

I wish to make a **listview of array(s)**, but i can't seem to get it to work, you can see my code a bit down. I'm trying to have my listview contain `Bitmap[]`, `String[]`, and `double[]` but according to my code&eclipse i can't do so... I have to convert them into plain botmaps, strings and doubles, which would take 4ever.

ConnectMySQL is the place where I connect to my database, and retrieve the information. I'm storing 100 different things(bitmaps, strings, doubles) in my arrays. everything is stored in the [] format exept for the bitmap, orignally it's stored in something called `ArrayList<Bitmap>` however I'm making it into `Bitmap[]`. But how do i get the arrays into my listview?

```
public class LVFinal extends Activity{
ArrayList<Bitmap> aMaster;
    Bitmap[] bitmapArray;
    String[] sMaster;
    Double[] dMaster;
    double[] doubleArray;

    private List<LVSecond> myList = new ArrayList<LVSecond>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        aMaster = ConnectMySQL.getRankingPic();
        sMaster = ConnectMySQL.getName();
        dMaster = ConnectMySQL.getRank();
        //stringRet(); //same as below pretty much, ignore this!
        bitmapReturn(); //this will return a1, a2, a3 and so on, but in normal bitmap(s) so i can use it in my code for custom listview
        doubleReturn(); // same as above pretty much
        populatePicture();
        populateListView();
    }


    private void doubleReturn() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doubleArray = new double[dMaster.length];
        for(int k = 0; k < doubleArray.length; k++) {
            doubleArray[k] = (double) dMaster[k];
        }
    }


    /*private void stringRet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }*/


    private void bitmapReturn() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bitmapArray = new Bitmap[aMaster.size()];
        bitmapArray = aMaster.toArray(bitmapArray);
    }


    private void populatePicture() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myList.add(new LVSecond(sMaster, bitmapArray, doubleArray));

    }

    private void populateListView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayAdapter<LVSecond> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRanking);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LVSecond>{
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(LVFinal.this, R.layout.item_list, myList);
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
            }
            // Find the list to work with
            LVSecond currentList = myList.get(position);

            // Fill the view, picture
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_iv);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(currentList.getIconPic());;

            // Fill the name, persons name
            TextView name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_tvName);
            name.setText(currentList.getName());

            // Fill the score
            TextView rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_tvScore);
            rank.set;

            return itemView;
            //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }


    }
}


public class LVSecond {
private String[] name;
private Bitmap[] iconPic;
private double[] ranking;

public LVSecond(String[] name, Bitmap[] bitmapArray, double[] getRanking){
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.iconPic = bitmapArray;
    this.ranking = getRanking;

}

public String[] getName() {
    return name;
}
public Bitmap[] getIconPic() {
    return iconPic;
}
public double[] getRanking() {
    return ranking;
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you write a POJO class which has Bitmap, String and Double? Use that class for your List and it's done.

Comment: @Aniruddha never heard of that, please allaborate, i could google it, but you know any good tutorials? preferably videos